# Rails model error object passing between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, model

I have looked around S.O. and other resources on the web and I am finding other questions that are similar to this one but not exactly like mine.  I'm sure that there is a response out there that works but I am asking this question for clarification as much as I am asking to find the solution.  Sorry if this sounds redundant to other questions but I have yet to find something that definitively answers my question.

I have an app where businesses have a listing page and each of those pages has a section where users can submit comments about that business.

Each business page is handled via a 'merchants_controller' using the 'show' action:

```
  def show
    @merchant = Merchant.merchant_link_test(params[:id])
    @title = @merchant.name
      # used inside maps javascript
      @map_height = '290px'
      @map_width = '350px' 
    @user_reviews = Review.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id).order("created_at....
    @user_reviews_count = Review.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id).count 
    @user_or_merchant = 'merchant'
    @review = Review.new
    @average_rating = Review.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id).average(:rating)
    @rounded = round_rating(@average_rating)
    @yelp_query = @merchant.yelp_string
    @yelp_count = yelp(@yelp_query, 'avg_rating')   
    @num_of_yelp = yelp(@yelp_query, 'review_count')
  end
```

I have a partial in the 'show' layout that displays a form for submitting comments about that business.  The form input is handled via a 'reviews_controller' using the 'create' action:

```
   def create
     user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
     id = user.id
     @merchant = Merchant.find(params[:review][:merchant_id])
     params[:review].store(:user_id, id)
     @review = Review.new(params[:review])
     if @review.save
       flash[:success] = "Your review was submitted!" 
       redirect_to @merchant
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error submitting your review"
       render :template => 'merchants/show', :locals => { :id => @merchant.id, }
     end
   end
```

The form uses the 'form_for' helper and looks like this:

```
   <% if signed_in? %>
 <div class = "comment_form">
    <%= form_for @review do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
        <div class = "field">
            <div id = "required_rating"> * </div><%= f.label :rating %>
            </br>
            <%= f.select :rating, [['', ''],['1 star (terrible)', 1],        
                            ['2 stars', 2],['3 stars', 3],['4 stars', 4],['5 stars 
            (bomb.com)', 5]] %>
            </br>
        </div>
        <div class = "field">
            <div id = "required_comment"> * </div><%= f.label :comment, 
                             "Comment (limit 1000 characters)" %>
            <br/>
            <%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => 80, :rows => 6 %>
        </div>
        <div id = "denotes_text"> * Denotes required field </div>
        <div class = "actions">
            <%= f.submit "Submit Review" %>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <div class = "sign_in_to_comment">
            <%= link_to "Sign in to submit a review of this merchant", 
                            signin_path %>
        </div>
     </div>
       <% end %>
```

I have a two tables and two models, 'merchants' and 'reviews' that handle the data for the respective resources.  My 'routes' file looks like this:

```
   resources :merchants, :only => [ :new, :create, :show ]

      match '/merchants/:name', :to => 'merchants#show'
      match '/merchants/:id/all', :to => 'comments#all_comments_merchant', :as => :all
      match '/merchants/:id/map', :to => 'merchants#map', :as => :map

   resources :reviews, :only => [ :create ]
```

My issue is that when a user submits a comment, if an error is generated via my validations in the model, the error object is passed back to the create action in the 'reviews_controller.'  I then want to display that error message on the 'merchant_show_page' but need to pass the error object from the 'reviews_controller' back to the 'merchants_controller.'

From what I have read, it seems like the error object has some 'automagic' functionality when being passed between actions within the same controller.  Specifically, it seems like the model knows the action that submitted the data and returns the error object using 'render' without having to initialize any instance variables on the page.

A few of the solutions that I have seen regarding similar questions:
  1.  Move the form submission action into the 'merchants_controller' and lose the 
  'reviews_controller' altogether.
  2.  Use 'redirect_to' instead of 'render' and pass the error object as a variable in the 
  redirect call.

It seems like there has to be an easy, 'rails way' to do this.  Having separate controllers seems to make logical sense and it allows me to keep merchants and reviews as separate resources which, from what I have read, is the proper rails convention I should be shooting for.  Is this just an issue where there is not a proper 'rails way' to do it?  If so, what other rails convention should I be defaulting to?

Any help that can be given would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your help,

noob :)

Comment: Just some quick pointers: 1) What the hell is `merchant_link_test`? Try `find`: `@merchant = Merchant.find(params[:id])`

Comment: 2) You don't need to use `where` when looking up associated records: `@user_reviews = @merchant.reviews.order("created_at DESC").limit(10).all`

Comment: 3) Use a counter_cache instead of doing an extra query on every request: `@user_reviews_count = @merchant.reviews_count`

Comment: Corey, I appreciate the comments.  Merchant link test allows users to type the name of the merchant into the url and still have it go to the right merchant page

Comment: ActiveRecord doesn't have some magical elusive "error object" that gets "passed between actions". `ActiveModel::Validations`, which gets mixed into `ActiveRecord::Base` (which your model inherits), adds the errors *to the model instance*. If you redirect to another action, you're releasing that object and so your errors disappear.

Comment: Then name it appropriately. `Merchant#find_by_name_or_id` or (and this would be better) constrain your routes so either a numerical ID is captured in `params[:id]` *or* a text name is captured in `params[:name]` and your action can call the appropriate finder method based on availability of one of these parameters.